# generating certificate keys for OpenVPN in Windows

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, certificate

I was looking into setting up OpenVPN on Windows... I've never done this before and was reading through their documentation and installation [tutorials](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#install)..

As in the newest realease, easy-rsa is not included and I need this for the initial setup. I downloaded it from the [github](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa) directory, but I am not sure how to correctly implement it in the OpenVPN folder structure... I just created a new easy-rsa folder and copied everything in there.

When I run init-config in C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\easy-rsa" I just get the usual

*"'init-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."*

I assume this is due to missing Windows Paths (in Environment Variables settings). I tried to follow readme files on the easy-rsa github, namely this one - *github dot com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/master/distro/windows/README-Windows.txt#L4* *
but wasn't able to get past this issue.

I was surprised that I have not found many tutorials and information on how to setup OpenVPN from start to finish in Windows, considering that it's quite popular nowadays... proves to be quite a complicated process.

Anybody can give me hints on how to move forward ?

*link limitations, sorry

Comment: [This](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic19629.html) is the Long AND Short Answer for EasyRSA at this time.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, OpenVPN have not done a particularly good job of the current EasyRSA Release on Github.  I post this link for Information:

- https://forums.openvpn.net/topic19629.html

The problem you are experiencing is due to the fact that the Official Download Link for the latest EasyRSA version is incomplete.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the issue. I have now got the files from the older 'stable' version of easy-rsa and tried to run the init-config again, from both the easy-rsa directory (where I copied all the downloaded files) and also from the binary directory. Still got he same "'init-config' is not recognized as.... 
http://s1.postimg.org/vrm508hkf/image.png
http://s1.postimg.org/zci0jgm3z/image.png

Comment: You must start EasyRSA with the `EasyRSA-Start.bat` file .. I **suggest** you Read the Help file `README-Windows.txt` included in the download

Comment: 404 - that link is not found